# oracle forms firefox / jpi-version restriction

Tags: java, linux, forms, oracle, firefox

I'd like to know if it's possible to "lie" about my jpi-version to not be blocked when i try to start a forms servlet.
I made my Linux / firefox java activated but when i try to access my forms app just like i use to do with IE, i got an error telling i don't have the right plugins.

So i wonder if it's possible, client side, to answer with attended version and arch to the following section of the forms file :

> codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4_2-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,2,06"<>
>   PARAM NAME="TYPE"       VALUE="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.4.2_06"<
>   EMBED SRC="" PLUGINSPAGE="http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/1.4.2_06/index.html"
>           TYPE="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.4.2_06"<